# Expected value of the longest run of red balls

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-distributions

Suppose there's an urn containing $r$ red balls and $b$ blue balls. At each trial, I'm drawing a ball at random from the urn, without replacement. Let $R$ denote the event of drawing a red ball, and let $B$ denote the event of drawing a blue ball. I'm conducting $r+b$ trials of this experiment. So, there are a total of $r+b \choose r$ equally likely possibilities.

From this setting, it is clear that both $\Pr$[$R$ at $k^{th}$ trial] and $\Pr$[$B$ at $k^{th}$ trial] depend on the outcomes of the previous $k-1$ trials.

I'm interested in finding the distribution of the longest run of red balls, and thus its expected value. How do I approach this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem can be solved by using a recursion. Let $p(r,b,L)$ be the probability that the longest run of red balls is larger than $L$. Then $p(r,b,L)=1-q(r,b,L)$, where $q(r,b,L)$  is the probability that there is no run of red balls of lenghth $L+1$. This probability can be obtained from the recursion

$q(r,b,L)=\frac{b}{r+b}q(r,b-1,L)+\sum_{k=1}^{L}\frac{r}{r+b}\times\cdots \times \frac{r-(k-1)}{r+b-(k-1)}\times\frac{b}{r+b-k}q(r-k,b-1,L)$.

The expected value of the longest run of red balls is $1+\sum_{L=1}^{r-1}p(r,b,L)$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Could you explain how you got the recursion though?

Comment: To get the recursion for $q(r,b,L)$, consider the first $L+1$ picks of a ball from the urn and condition on the first pick resulting in a blue ball. Under the condition that the first $k$ picks result in a red ball and the $k+1$ th pick in a blue ball with $0\leq k\leq L$, the probability of no run of lenghth $L+1$ is $q(r-k,b-1,L)$. Next apply the law conditional probability.

Comment: Oh, I understand now. Thank you! :)

Comment: I had a related question in mind; using this method, one can get the cumulative distribution of the lengths of the longest run. Though this is sufficient to obtain the expected value of the longest run, I was wondering if there's a way to obtain the probability distribution, i.e. the explicit probability values for each $L \in \{1,2,...r\}$?

Comment: $P(X=j)=P(X>j-1)-P(X>j)$

Comment: No, unless I'm mistaken, I believe that RHS gives me only $P( j-1< X \leq j)$.

Comment: Oh, I understand now. Since $X$ is discrete and can take only integer values, $P( j-1< X \leq j) = P (X=j)$. Thank you! :)